# Using Java Object after sax parsing

Tags: java, methods, saxparser

i create an Method that will be parse an XML File on Java 8.
I will be work but i cant use the parseBookObject and this collected Datas to other Ways.

```js
public static void parseISBN(fileObject) throws ParseException, ...
{
 // New Book Object with Datas from FileObject
 Book bookObject = new Book (fileObject.getPath, ...)
  
 // parse ISBN with marc21
 Marc21.parseISBN(bookObject); 
}

// Class Mark21
public static void parseISBN(Book bookObject) throws ...
{
  ...
  
  SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        saxFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        SAXParser saxParser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();

        xmlReader.setContentHandler(new Marc21Handler());
        xmlReader.parse(sruAbfrage);
}


public class Marc21Handler extends DefaultHandler 
{
 ...
 Book parserBookObject = new Book();
 
 public void startDocument ...
 public void startElement ...
 public void characters...
 ...
 if ("245".equals(this.bufferNummer)) {
            if ("a".equals(this.bufferCode)) {
                parserBookObjekt.setTitel(zeichenkette);
    ..
    }
    ...
 public void endElement...
}
```

My Problem are, that i collect the XML Datas into "parseBookObject" inside the Handler. I dont know how i can return back the Object to the Method "parseISBN(fileObject)" in this Method i want to use the Datas of collected informations.

Before i want to give the object "bookObject" to the Handler for collection XML Datas to these object and will give it back. I cant give any other object from xmlReader or Parser to Handler?!
Then i created a new object in Handler called "parserBookObject" and want after collect the Datas give back to the Method "parseISBN(fileObject)".

Know anyone how i can do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Store the `Marc21Handler` instance in a local variable and return the field after you finished parsing.

Something like that:

```
public static void parseISBN(Book bookObject) throws ...
{
    ...

    SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    saxFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    SAXParser saxParser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
    March21Handler handler = new Marc21Handler()
    xmlReader.setContentHandler(handler);
    xmlReader.parse(sruAbfrage);
    return handler.parserBookObject;
}
```

But you might want do to yourself a favor and use something different, like JAXB/XStream/Jackson. Maybe even Stax if you insist on using a streaming parser.

Answer (score 0):

Create the Marc21Handler object as a field of the class, then add a method to that class, like `getBookObject()` that returns the object you parsed. Call that method from `parseISBN()`